# Multiplexer vs RPI Compute Module for stereo camera?

Tags: raspicam, compute-module, picamera

I am looking to capture images simultanously using 2 picameras (tried USB the FPS is low).  It seems like there are 2 options:

- Raspberry Pi compute module 3 with IO board which gives 2 CSI ports(https://www.adafruit.com/product/3442)
- A multiplexer CSI add on board (http://www.ivmech.com/magaza/en/development-modules-c-4/ivport-v2-raspberry-pi-camera-module-v2-multiplexer-p-107)

Which of these 2 options would be better?  I want the images as close together from the 2 cameras as possible as well as getting good FPS.

Answer (score 1):

The compute module allows 2 x 720p@30 fps. The multiplexer board does not allow simultaneous operation of multiple cameras, only a round-robin scheme. Switching between cameras will take some time and interrupt the video feed.

Comment: Do you know if the picamera can plug straight into the io board or do I need to buy an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in the latest MagPi: https://stereopi.com/

It looks like it is perfect but know no more than I read in the magazine.